# showing that all the angles in a regular pentagon are the same euclid style.

Tags: geometry

[image: Problem]

EDIT

We are given that angle $ABC \cong$ angle $BAE \cong $ Angle BCD we also have that every side example $AB\cong BC \cong CD \cong DE \cong DA$

EDIT2:
Because of what is stated in the drawn picture we actually have that angle $AED \cong $ angle EDC as the two sides BD and ED are congruent so the angles inside must be equal as isosceles triangle  so same angle + angle 2 means that angle $AED \cong $ angle EDC but im not sure how to show that they are equal to one of the given angles.

Comment: cant you argue by symmetry?

Comment: Basically im only supposed to have to use postulates 1-34 of Euclid or id be done a long time ago... doing it without modern ish methods is very hard imo. also your profile picture is hilarious.

Comment: i dont know what Euclids postulates are. But, one way to do this is to show that the regular polygon (all equal angles) satisfies the property, and show that if you have another angle the polygon cannot be "closed" and is hence not a polygon at all. Thus, the conditions you describe uniquely classify the above polygon and then you are done.

Comment: Did not Euclid circumscribe in a a circumferemce, making your thesis almost immediate? upon a quick search this popped up, maybe interesting, https://math.berkeley.edu/~kpmann/pentagonconst.pdf

Comment: Theres gotta be a simpler way to prove this with the given information...

Comment: @Faust, as a matter of fact, what is it you are given? The fact sides are equal? Because you start the post with some given info on the angles, could you clarify maybe?

Comment: Edited to post to reflect clearly that we are given every side is congruent to every other side. and that we are given 3 angles are the same inside and wish to prove the last two are equal to them

Comment: $BCD$ is congruent to $ABC$ (two sides and included angle), as also is $EAB$ (same reason). So $BE=AD=BC$. Then $AED$ and $CDE$ are congruent to $ABC$ (equivalent sides are equal).

Comment: yeah that is the best i have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thoughts.
I am not entirely sure at what stage of the Elements Euclid proves the fact the sum of the internal angles of a triangle equals $\pi$.
Nevertheless I believe it can be proven with very little on top of the Fifth Postulate, and I hope it falls within the permitted tools, following the OP's request.

As the sides are all equal as are the angles $BAE$ and $BCD$, the diagonals $BE$ and $BD$ have equal length. 
Hence the angles $BED$ and $BDE$ are equal.
The angles $AEB$ and $BDC$ are also equal, as they belong to triangles we know congruent by hypothesis. We still need to check $AED = ABC$.

Now, looking at $ABC$ and $BAE$ one could say $$ ABC = 2 ABE + EBD $$
and
 $$ ABC = BAE = \pi - 2 AEB$$

concluding that $$ EBD = 2 ABC - \pi$$
hence $$BED = \pi - ABC $$
and we can then show that $BED + ABE = ABC$

Comment: Im with you up until this line: hence $$BED = \pi - ABC $$ what justification for it ?

Comment: Looking at the triangle BED, once the angle EBD is found, and knowing the triangle is isosceles, I find $BED$ as $\frac{1}{2} (\pi - EBD)$

Comment: At the end of the day, all the above is a way to justify what we know,  that the sum of internal angles of a pentagon equals $3 \pi$, and further $ABC =  \frac{3}{5} \pi$, and $ABE = EBD = DBC = \frac{1}{5} \pi$